# PubSub + DataFlow or PubSub + Function trigger for updating BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm new to building pipelines, and I was using the twitter api to stream data. My current approach is as follows:

1. I send the streamed data to a Topic on pub/sub, which triggers the cloud function to insert the message into BigQuery after processing.
2. The other approach recommended was using pub/sub + DataFlow, but I'm not sure how that makes a difference.

Can someone elaborate on the pros and cons of the two approaches ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Benefits with Dataflow over cloud functions when moving data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197653/benefits-with-dataflow-over-cloud-functions-when-moving-data)

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you !